# pushed code to gerrit after cherry-pick by mistake

Tags: git, gerrit, cherry-pick

My code is based on a cherry-pick I have done to another patch.
I pushed it by mistake as the other patch is not ready yet. So in gerrit I see the other patch files as well.
How do I make now my pushed patch re-based without the other files that came in from the other patch?

Answer (score 0):

To restore the branch to where it was before the cherry-pick, do this (where `n` is the number of cherry-picked commits):

```
git reset --hard HEAD~n
git push -f
```

Note that a force-push might mess up the commit history for anyone who has pulled your branch after your cherry-pick.

If you want to cherry-pick parts of a commit (just the one file), it can for instance be done this way:

```
git cherry-pick <hash>
git reset --soft HEAD~1
//revert unwanted changes and commit
git push
```